WPF Binding get some wrong in MahApps.Metro but it can run
**In my xaml: * *
<! -- Items -->
<Controls: HamburgerMenu. ItemsSource>
    <Controls: HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
        <Controls: HamburgerMenuItem Command="{Binding LinkViewModel. isMVIRCommand}" Label="WVIR"></Controls: HamburgerMenuItem>
        <Controls: HamburgerMenuItem Command="{Binding LinkViewModel. isTemperatureCommand}" Label="temperature"></Controls: HamburgerMenuItem>
    </Controls: HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
</Controls: HamburgerMenu. ItemsSource>
**In my LinkViewModel: **
public DelegateCommand isMVIRCommand { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand isTemperatureCommand { get; set; }
isMVIRCommand = new DelegateCommand(isMVIR);
isTemperatureCommand = new DelegateCommand(ChangeToTemperature);
private void ChangeToTemperature()
{
    isMV = "Collapsed";
    isIR = "Collapsed";
    isTemperature = "Visible";
}

private void isMVIR()
{
    isMV = "Visible";
    isIR = "Collapsed";
    isTemperature = "Collapsed";
}
**follow it's wrong: **
LinkViewModel. isMVIRCommand HamburgerMenuItem. Command ICommand FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement can't find the target element management.
LinkViewModel. IsTemperatureCommand HamburgerMenuItem.Com and ICommand FrameworkElement or can't find the target element management FrameworkContentElement.

I'm sure it has been Binding in LinkViewModel, but when I run my project, it can run for my expectations, but my wpf designer got wrong with me. I wish someone could help me find the problem

I know the reason why i can run the project but my wpf designer got wrong with me.Please read my Code.
<Controls:HamburgerMenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.LinkViewModel.isMVIRCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}}" Label="WVIR"/>
<Controls:HamburgerMenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.LinkViewModel.isTemperatureCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}}" Label="temperature"/>

I add the RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}}.They told wpf designer search up for designer-tree when it can found the MetroWindow.And in my situation,My MetroWindow DataContext has been set MainWindowViewModel,and my LinkViewModel is a element in MainWindowModel,so it can been found in WPF designer
